# Error "bad function call" when passing lambda to STL set

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, set

I'm trying to pass a lambda as a sorting criterion to a set of indices of type int. I have used an unordered_map to map the indices to their values and passed it by value to the lambda which takes two indices and returns bool.

The code compiles but I'm getting "bad function call" error at run-time.

I've used std::function<> type wrapper to declare the lambda instead of using decltype() which was giving an error.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    while (T--)
    {
        int N;
        cin >> N;

        unordered_map<int, int> M;
        function<bool(int, int)> l = [M](int i1, int i2)->bool { return M.at(i1) > M.at(i2); };
        set<int, function<bool(int, int)>> S;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        {
            int p;
            cin >> p;

            M[i] = p;
            S.insert(i);
        }

        vector<vector<int>> Adj(N + 1);
        for (int i = 1; i <= N - 1; ++i)
        {
            int u, v;
            cin >> u >> v;

            Adj[u].push_back(v);
            Adj[v].push_back(u);
        }

        int maximum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        {
            S.erase(i);
            for (int e : Adj[i])
                S.erase(e);
            cout << *S.cbegin() << ' ';
            for (int e : Adj[i])
                S.insert(e);
            S.insert(i);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1
6
5 10 15 20 25 30
1 3
2 3
3 4
4 5
4 6
```

I have this code inside a try-catch block and it's printing "bad function call" when I enter the second value (10 in the input)

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. The code you show doesn't use the lambda. Or perhaps that *is* the problem? That you don't tell the set to use your lambda, and instead it attempts to use some unspecified function?

Comment: Are you trying to set a predicate for `std::set` by doing this: `set<int, function<bool(int, int)>> S;`? If so, I don't think the syntax is correct.

Comment: You're capturing an empty map. Looking things up in it is a bad idea.

Comment: Also watch out that `[M]` "captures by copy", meaning that changes to the `M` in the containing function won't have any effect on the `M` used inside the lambda. It looks like you want `[&M]` to "capture by reference". (But then make sure no copy of that `std::function` lives longer than `M`!)

Comment: Before using std::function<>, I was using auto and passing the type in the set using decltype(l) and it was not compiling so I tried this and it compiled. Should I upload the whole code?

Comment: @lucieon, try to write: `set<int, l> S;` instead.

Comment: Perhaps [this `std::set` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) could be helpful? Especially [the constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set).

Comment: @vahancho I'm getting error "l is not a typename".

Comment: Typo.  `S.insert(i)` should be `S.insert(l)`.    That your reward for using variable names that are visually similar (`l` looks a lot like `i`, even if it isn't identical) for distinct variables.   Also, the lamda capture should use a reference, not capture by value.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried [&M] and still getting runtime error.

Comment: @Peter I want to enter the index i and S is a set of type int not of type of l.

Answer (score 2):

> I have this code inside a try-catch block and it's printing "bad function call"

This happens when you try to invoke default initialized `std::function`:

> std::bad_function_call if *this does not store a callable function target, i.e. !*this == true.

provided in documentation of [`std::function>::operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator())

You do not pass your functor to `std::set` constructor when you initialize the object as you using default ctor for `std::set`:

```
set<int, function<bool(int, int)>> S;
```

so this should be used instead:

```
set<int, function<bool(int, int)>> S( l );
```

and your lambda should capture `M` by reference as any changes you made later on `M` would not be reflected in this lambda as it captures `M` by value.

Comment: I uploaded the complete code but I don't understand what you're saying, can you explain in detail? Edit: I tried passing l in the constructor of S but still the same error.

Comment: @lucieon You need to tell the set `S` to use your lambda.

Comment: What particularly you do not understand? You create your set `S` using default ctor which default initializes the functor hense you get the exception. I showed you the line you should fix.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok I forget to pass M by reference, it's working now. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Please do not change your code after you asked and answered, this invalidates answers

Comment: @Slava ok. I'll change it back to original. Thanks!